# dataTables not working properly. Links are good i think. What's wrong here?

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables

I'm still a newbie when it comes to developing. I just want to ask what's wrong with this code? I'm trying to use DataTables but unfortunately, my table is still not working properly. All my links are properly directed to their folders. Is it the order of the links? Help please.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Admin Dashboard</title>
<link href="../../../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../../../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../dist/dtables/dtables1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../../dist/dtables/dtables1/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="../../../dist/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="../../../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="../../../dist/dtables/dtables1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../dist/dtables/dtables1/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

```
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">ITS - 101</h1>
                        <table  id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Student Number</th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Middle Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Age</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Student Number</th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Middle Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Age</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                    include "../../adminconn.php";

                                    $sel = "Select * from its101";

                                    $res = mysqli_query ($conn,$sel);

                                    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){

                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){    
                                            echo "<tr><td>".$row["studentnumber"]."</td><td>".$row["fname"]."</td><td>".$row["mname"]."</td><td>".$row["lname"]."</td><td>".$row["age"]."</td></tr>";       
                                        } echo "</tbody>";
                                        echo "</table>";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "No data yet";                 
                                        }
                                    $conn -> close();
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Are the scripts and css not in order? or is it the table itself?

Comment: Replace `$('example').DataTable();`  with `$('#example').DataTable();` and you're good to go with the above code.

Answer (score -1):

I have done it at last! I just needed to do it from the scratch again, turns out the `jquery.dataTables.css` and `jquery.dataTables.js` is all i needed, not the `jquery.dataTables.min.css` and `jquery.dataTables.min.js`!